# improve regex pcre php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

In my project (php), I got some regexs(pcre) like this one :

`preg_match('/[\s^0-9]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[\s^0-9]{0,1}/',$chanson['nom'],$resultPreg1)`

This regex catch two numbers who can be delimited or not by a single space, and can't be delimited by number. What I want to do is, that there is or a space (and no number) in beginning, or a space (and no number) at the end. But it must have at least one delimiter.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Examples would work very well in this situation ;-)

Comment: I agree with Jack.  This question will be far clearer if you provide some sample strings.  This will give your question context and remove any lingering doubt about what fringe cases might look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to split it up and test each case:

```
/\s\d{2}\D|\D\d{2}\s/
```

This will match a space, two digits, and any non-digit character **or** a non-digit character, two digits and a space.

Note: `\d` is a digit, equivalent to `[0-9]`.  `\D` is a non-digit, equivalent to `[^0-9]`.

The above regex requires there to be at least one non-digit on each side of the numbers, however.  Also, if you had a pattern like `.11 22.`, it would not match both numbers, because the space would be eaten up by the first match.  If this is a problem, you can use look-arounds:

```
/\s\d{2}(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\d{2}\s/
```

This matches a space, then two digits not followed by another digit **or** two digits not preceded by a digit, followed by a space.

`(?!...)` is negative look-ahead.  It means "the match cannot be followed by this."

`(?<!...)` is negative look-behind, meaning "the match cannot be preceded by this."

Comment: ok thank you. I didn'nt knew \d so usefull...
so we can use | as or and & as and ?

Comment: If string is reached until the end at the last digit. Did this regex match ?

Comment: Yes, `|` means *or*. If you need it to only apply to part of the pattern, put it within a group: `/(?:spl|dr)at/` matches "splat" or "drat". There is nothing to mean *and*, because by default the pattern has to match everything.

Comment: @vekah, see the updated second version, which will match two digits even at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: I use `(*)`  for catchind `\d{2}` did (?!*) catch something in `$resultPreg1` ?

Comment: @vekah, I'm not sure what you mean by that.  `(?!*)` is not valid however.

Comment: I mean I use paranthese for catching the double number and use it in PHP. Won't preg catch what I didn't want `(?!\d)` in $resultPreg array ?

Comment: @vekah, preg only captures regular parentheses.  Parentheses with special meaning such as `(?!...)`, `(?:...)`, etc. do not capture.  Any time the first character in parentheses is `?`, it has a special meaning and is not a capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix the negative and positive character classes in a single set of square brackets. A "space" OR "not a number" could be written `\s|[^0-9]`.   But a space *isn't* a number, so no need to put it in specially, just `[^0-9]` will suffice for you.  Your syntax for "zero or one" of `{0,1}` is technically correct, but there is a much more concise syntax for the same thing: `?`.

```
preg_match('/[^0-9]?([0-9]{2})[^0-9]?/',$chanson['nom'],$resultPreg1)
```

You could almost use word breaks around your number to get what you are looking for except it wouldn't find numbers embedded in letters like "abc23def".

```
preg_match('/\b([0-9]{2})\b/',$chanson['nom'],$resultPreg1)
```